# Looking for a note-taking app that's designed to save quotations

Tags: note-taking

Basically, I spend a lot of time reading artcles in my browser (and on Instapaper and Pocket when on my phone), I even read books in the browser.

I am looking for a solution through which I can simply highlight the "quote" I like in a page, and save it. Right now, I am using Evernote for this, along with the extension. But since Evernote is not specialized for this, the selected text becomes the body and the page title becomes the title of the note. Which is fine. I could also use Google Keep for this, which allows for labels as well, but since I use it for lots of other things as well, I don't want to clutter it.

I am looking for an app specialized for this purpose.